# appending data from a text file into a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

i am new to python and i need to read numbers from a text file and pass those in order into a list here is what i came up with :

```
liste = []
with open("MDATX3.014") as fa:
    lines = fa.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            liste.append(word)
            print(liste)
```

and i had the result like this
[image]

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `print(liste)` outside the loop if you don't want to see its intermediate values while it is being appended with new values:

```
liste = []
with open("MDATX3.014") as fa:
    lines = fa.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            liste.append(word)
print(liste)
```

Comment: i will in 3 mins)